# count same item between many rows and columns on one query

Tags: mysql

I have the next table:

```
 id| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5|
 ----------------------------
 01| 23 | 19 | 30 | 30 | 30|
 ---------------------------
 02| 23 | 40 | 30 | 30 | 30|
 ----------------------------
 03| 23 | 20 | 19 | 30 | 30|
 ----------------------------
 04| 23 | 19 | 30 | 30 | 30|
 ----------------------------
 05| 23 | 23 | 23 | 19 | 30|
 ----------------------------
```

in this table the count of number 19 is 4

I need a query to count how many times each number appears in the table, searching in many rows and columns, or at least number 19 with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `IF` with `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(id=19,1,0) + IF(c1=19,1,0) + IF(c2=19,1,0) +
     IF(c3=19,1,0) + IF(c4=19,1,0) + IF(c5=19,1,0)) 
FROM YourTable
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80eb1/1)

---

As pointed out, the IF statement isn't actually needed:

```
SELECT SUM((c1=19)+(c2=19)+(c3=19)+(c4=19))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Do you really think OP wants to count the id? The IFs are unnecessary too.

Comment: @Arth -- good point, the `IFs` are not necessary.  In regards to the id, I assume not, but I don't know.  This was just to give another shorter option.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this is a better method, I fancied an answer up with a JOIN to avoid repeating the search criteria, but essentially it is the same.

Comment: sgeddes: this works well; going further, is there a query for each number?

Comment: @Kirikou -- sure, you just need a numbers table to `join` with.  then you can `group by` that number.  Here's a quick condensed example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80eb1/10

Answer (score 2):

I'd `union` all the columns, and then just `count` the values:

```
SELECT   c, COUNT(*) 
FROM     (SELECT c1 AS c FROM my_table
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c2 FROM my_table
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c3 FROM my_table
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c4 FROM my_table
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c5 FROM my_table) t
GROUP BY c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) FROM tablename where c1 = 19 OR c2 = 19 or c3 = 19 etc
```

Comment: This won't work if you have a row with 19 in more than one column.

Comment: which judging by the example given, doesn't occur and nor was that condition given.

Comment: Lol "I need a query to count how many times each number appears in the table".. have a look at 30! You may as well change your query to `SELECT 4`

Comment: @Arth don't be petty and continue with your quote: "...or at least number 19 with MySQL."

Comment: @user3791372 Apologies for being petty, but I see you have conveniently left out "searching in many rows and columns". Your answer doesn't do that, not for 19 either, it just happens to work because 19 doesn't appear in multiple columns for the same row. Given the nature of the problem it is as good as `SELECT 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the SUM method:

```
SELECT SUM(
           (t1.c1=x.num) 
         + (t1.c2=x.num) 
         + (t1.c3=x.num)
         + (t1.c4=x.num)
         + (t1.c5=x.num)
         ) count 
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN (SELECT 19 num) x
```

Comment: I agree, why would this be downvoted?  It's close to my answer, but not the same.  I'll give it a +1 as I prefer the `join` over writing out `19` multiple times...